Make the formula-checkbox clickable
I would like to make the formula-checkbox D9:D16 clickable to unchecked even if D8 makes D9:D16 checked.
I tried ={D8} on D9:D16 but the state of the checkboxes is determined by the underlying formula, so it cannot toggled by clicking.
Screenshot of sheet:


While use formula then what is reason to click it manually. You can change formula and based on that formula output checkbox tick will change.

Making 1 Way Sync with Checkbox of Google Sheets
Note: It might be a little tricky to implement your requirement using Google Sheet Formula. As a workaround I suggest accomplishing this using Apps Script.
How to use Google Apps Script in Google Sheets:
1.) Open the spreadsheet you want to use.
2.) Click on Extensions in the menu.
3.) Select Apps Script from the options.
4.) Copy and paste the code below.
You can try this code:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) return;

  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;

  if (range.getA1Notation() === 'D8') {
    const value = range.getValue();
    const checkboxesRange = sheet.getRange('D9:D16');
    checkboxesRange.setValue(value);
  }
}

The script makes sure that when you change the checkbox in D8, all checkboxes in D9 will automatically reflect that change, but only for the specified sheet (D9:D16).
Sample Output:


Reference/s:
onEdit
